# Getting all entries whose birthday is today in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following query and I need to implement a Mailer that needs to be send out to all clients who's Birthday is today. This happens on a daily manner. Now what I need to achieve is only to select the Birthday clients using a Postgres SQL query instead of filtering them in PHP.

The date format stored in the database is YYYY-MM-DD eg. 1984-03-13

What I have is the following query

```
SELECT cd.firstname,
       cd.surname, 
       SUBSTRING(cd.birthdate,6),
       cd.email 
FROM client_contacts AS cd 
   JOIN clients AS c ON c.id = cd.client_id 
WHERE SUBSTRING(birthdate,6) = '07-20';
```

Are there better ways to do this query than the one I did above?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could set your where clause to:

```
WHERE
    DATE_PART('day', birthdate) = date_part('day', CURRENT_DATE)
AND
    DATE_PART('month', birthdate) = date_part('month', CURRENT_DATE)
```

Comment: what about people that are borned last year?

Comment: Apparently i need to go to bed instead of answering questions on SO. I'll edit.

Comment: @jordan - Thanks for the efforts, but none of our clients are 1 day old ;-)

Comment: @Jordan - I think I have another problem I get a Syntax error on CURRENT_DATE()), think it might be because of the Old Version of Postgres thats installed on the server , version PostgreSQL 8.1.22

Comment: That should be `date_part()` not `datepart()` and `CURRENT_DATE` not `CURRENT_DATE()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: like I said, I should've just gone to bed :) Thanks for the corrections. I have updated my answer with the correct form, for posterity's sake.

Comment: Hehe. I still think that my approach is better for people/contracts dated Feb 29th, though. ;-)

Comment: Just curious, to enable use of index for this WHERE, do you need to define an index (possibly 2-column) with `date_part('day', column)` ?

Comment: I ended up with this solution too, except that when `CURRENT_DATE` is the Feb 28th on a non-leap year, the query becomes `date_part('month', birthdate) = 2 AND date_part('day', birthdate) IN (28, 29)` to also match people born on leap day.

Answer (score 5):

In case it matters, the age function will let you work around the issue of leap years:

```
where age(cd.birthdate) - (extract(year from age(cd.birthdate)) || ' years')::interval = '0'::interval
```

It case you want performance, you can actually wrap the above with an arbitrary starting point (e.g. `'epoch'::date`) into a function, too, and use an index on it:

```
create or replace function day_of_birth(date)
  returns interval
as $$
  select age($1, 'epoch'::date)
         - (extract(year from age($1, 'epoch'::date)) || ' years')::interval;
$$ language sql immutable strict;

create index on client_contacts(day_of_birth(birthdate));

...

where day_of_birth(cd.birthdate) = day_of_birth(current_date);
```

(Note that it's not *technically* immutable, since dates depend on the timezone. But the immutable part is needed to create the index, and it's safe if you're not changing the time zone all over the place.)

---

EDIT: I've just tested the above a bit, and the index suggestion actually doesn't work for feb-29th. Feb-29th yields a day_of_birth of 1 mon 28 days which, while correct, needs to be added to Jan-1st in order to yield a valid birthdate for the current year.

```
create or replace function birthdate(date)
  returns date
as $$
  select (date_trunc('year', now()::date)
         + age($1, 'epoch'::date)
         - (extract(year from age($1, 'epoch'::date)) || ' years')::interval
         )::date;
$$ language sql stable strict;

with dates as (
  select d
  from unnest('{
    2004-02-28,2004-02-29,2004-03-01,
    2005-02-28,2005-03-01
  }'::date[]) d
)
select d,
       day_of_birth(d),
       birthdate(d)
from dates;

     d      | day_of_birth  | birthdate  
------------+---------------+------------
 2004-02-28 | 1 mon 27 days | 2011-02-28
 2004-02-29 | 1 mon 28 days | 2011-03-01
 2004-03-01 | 2 mons        | 2011-03-01
 2005-02-28 | 1 mon 27 days | 2011-02-28
 2005-03-01 | 2 mons        | 2011-03-01
(5 rows)
```

And thus:

```
where birthdate(cd.birthdate) = current_date
```

Answer (score 2):

The [@Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311339/jordan) answer is correct but, it wont work if your date format is string. If it is string you have type cast it using to_date function. then apply the date_part function.

If date of birth (DOB) is 20/04/1982 then the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM public."studentData" where date_part('day',TO_DATE("DOB", 'DD/MM/YYYY'))='20' 
AND date_part('month',TO_DATE("DOB", 'DD/MM/YYYY'))='04';
```

or

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE("DOB", 'DD/MM/YYYY'))='04' AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM TO_DATE("DOB", 'DD/MM/YYYY'))='20'
```

I add double quotes to table name("studentData") and field name ("DOB") because it was string.

Credit to [@Jordan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311339/jordan)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE date_part('month', cd.birthdate) = '07' AND date_part('day', cd.birthdate) = '20'
```

you can read more about this [here](http://www.digipedia.pl/pgsql/8.1/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Thx, but this error comes up HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: datepart() is not a Postgres function, it should be date_part()

Comment: Yes I missed the underscore. But you shoud use @Jordan solution it's the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE 0 = extract(DAY FROM age(dob)) + extract (MONTH FROM age(dob))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with something like:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(DOY FROM TIMESTAMP cd.birthdate) = EXTRACT(DOY FROM TIMESTAMP CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I thought about that too - Jordan's answer is the good one then :)

Comment: No, it isn't... He's extracting the year instead of the day, and that still won't solve the leap year. I'd use age(), personally (see my answer).

Answer (score -1):

The best way IMO is to use `to_char(birthday, 'MM-DD') in (?)` where you just give some date range mapped to `'MM-DD'` in place of `?`. Unless you have to support very big date ranges this solution is very simple, clean and bug resistant.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is, extract the person detail who would be wished using SQL manually, and send the wish separately manually. What if I suggest you a better approach?

Extract the wish details as excel and let [wishing app](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app) take care of everything.

At minimal it just need two things **excel file** with wish details (Date, name, email) and a configuration file (**application.properties**) and that is it, you are good to go.

Further there various [options to run](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Running) the application locally (Command line, foreground, background, docker, windows scheduler, unix cron etc) Cloud.

Application is [highly configurable](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Configurations-unleashed) , you can configure various details like:

- Workbook loading options
- Image options to send with wishes.
- SMTP Configurations
- Other application level configurations like, when to send wish, belated wish, logging etc.

  Disclaimer : I am the owner of the application