# Postgres birthdays selection

Tags: postgresql, intervals, date

I work with a Postgres database. This DB has a table with users, who have a birthdate (date field). Now I want to get all users who have their birthday in the upcoming week....

My first attempt: `SELECT id FROM public.users WHERE id IN (lange reeks) AND birthdate > NOW() AND birthdate < NOW() + interval '1 week'`

But this does not result, obviously because off the year. How can I work around this problem?

And does anyone know what happen to PG would go with the cases at 29-02 birthday?

Answer (score 11):

We can use a postgres function to do this in a really nice way.

Assuming we have a table `people`, with a date of birth in the column `dob`, which is a date, we can create a function that will allow us to index this column ignoring the year. (Thanks to [Zoltán Böszörményi](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/481E08F1.3000604@cybertec.at)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION indexable_month_day(date) RETURNS TEXT as $BODY$
  SELECT to_char($1, 'MM-DD');
$BODY$ language 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE INDEX person_birthday_idx ON people (indexable_month_day(dob));
```

Now, we need to query against the table, and the index. For instance, to get everyone who has a birthday in April of any year:

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE 
    indexable_month_day(dob) >= '04-01'
AND 
    indexable_month_day(dob) < '05-01';
```

There is one gotcha: if our start/finish period crosses over a year boundary, we need to change the query:

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE 
    indexable_month_day(dob) >= '12-29'
OR 
    indexable_month_day(dob) < '01-04';
```

To make sure we match leap-day birthdays, we need to know if we will 'move' them a day forward or backwards. In my case, it was simpler to just match on both days, so my general query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE 
    indexable_month_day(dob) > '%(start)%'
%(AND|OR)%
    indexable_month_day(dob) < '%(finish)%';
```

I have a django queryset method that makes this all much simpler:

```
def birthday_between(self, start, finish):
    """Return the members of this queryset whose birthdays
    lie on or between start and finish."""
    start = start - datetime.timedelta(1)
    finish = finish + datetime.timedelta(1)
    return self.extra(where=["indexable_month_day(dob) < '%(finish)s' %(andor)s indexable_month_day(dob) > %(start)s" % {
        'start': start.strftime('%m-%d'),
        'finish': finish.strftime('%m-%d'),
        'andor': 'and if start.year == finish.year else 'or'
    }]

def birthday_on(self, date):
    return self.birthday_between(date, date)
```

Now, I can do things like:

```
Person.objects.birthday_on(datetime.date.today())
```

Matching leap-day birthdays only on the day before, or only the day after is also possible: you just need to change the SQL test to a `>=' or '<=', and not adjust the start/finish in the python function.

Comment: Great solution. Worked perfectly for my needs. Cheers!

Comment: This solution seems great, but how these steps could be automated in django. I want to write a test for this function but in the test database there is not any defined function and I could not find a way to generate this function(indexable_month_day) from django and create an index using it.

Comment: You'll need to write a database migration that adds the function (and create the index).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not overly confident in this, but it seems to work in my testing. The key here is the `OVERLAPS` operator, and some date arithmetic.

I assume you have a table:

```
create temporary table birthdays (name varchar, bday date);
```

Then I put some stuff into it:

```
insert into birthdays (name, bday) values 
('Aug 24', '1981-08-24'), ('Aug 04', '1982-08-04'), ('Oct 10', '1980-10-10');
```

This query will give me the people with birthdays in the next week:

```
select * from 
  (select *, bday + date_trunc('year', age(bday)) + interval '1 year' as anniversary from birthdays) bd 
where 
  (current_date, current_date + interval '1 week') overlaps (anniversary, anniversary)
```

The `date_trunc` truncates the date at the year, so it should get you up to the current year. I wound up having to add one year. This suggests to me I have an off-by-one in there for some reason. Perhaps I just need to find a way to get dates to round up. In any case, there are other ways to do this calculation. `age` gives you the interval from the date or timestamp to today. I'm trying to add the years between the birthday and today to get a date in the current year.

The real key is using `overlaps` to find records whose dates overlap. I use the anniversary date twice to get a point-in-time.

Comment: I really like the "anniversary" idea, it makes everything looks so simple. No need to worry about things like leap year and year change. Regarding the off-by-one, I think you should only add one year to anniversary if it is before current date, else the query won't return the birthday boys and girls.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, to show the upcoming birthdays of the next 14 days I used this:

```
SELECT 
    -- 14 days before birthday of 2000
    to_char( to_date(to_char(c.birthdate, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') - interval '14 days' , 'YYYY-MM-dd')  as _14b_b2000,
    -- birthday of 2000
    to_date(to_char(c.birthdate, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') as date_b2000,
    -- current date of 2000
    to_date(to_char(current_date, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') as date_c2000,
    -- 14 days after current date of 2000
    to_char( to_date(to_char(current_date, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') + interval '14 days' , 'YYYY-MM-dd') as _14a_c2000,
    -- 1 year after birthday of 2000
    to_char( to_date(to_char(c.birthdate, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') + interval '1 year' , 'YYYY-MM-dd') as _1ya_b2000
FROM c
WHERE 
    -- the condition 
    -- current date of 2000 between 14 days before birthday of 2000 and birthday of 2000
    to_date(to_char(current_date, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') between 
        to_date(to_char(c.birthdate, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') - interval '14 days' and 
        to_date(to_char(c.birthdate, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') 
    or 
    -- 1 year after birthday of 2000 between current date of 2000 and 14 days after current date of 2000
    to_date(to_char(c.birthdate, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') + interval '1 year' between 
        to_date(to_char(current_date, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') and 
        to_date(to_char(current_date, '2000-MM-dd'), 'YYYY-MM-dd') + interval '14 days' 
;
```

So: 
To solve the leap-year issue, I set both birthdate and current date to 2000,
and handle intervals only from this initial correct dates.

To take care of the near end/beginning dates,
I compared first the 2000 current date to the 2000 birthday interval,
and in case current date is at the end of the year, and the birthday is at the beginning,
I compared the 2001 birthday to the 2000 current date interval.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that gets the right result, most of the time.

```
SELECT 
    (EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '1980-08-05'),
     EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE '1980-08-05')) 
IN (
    SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE + s.a) AS m,
           EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE + s.a) AS d 
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0, 6) AS s(a)
);
```

(it doesn't take care of leap years correctly; but you could use `extract` again to work the subselect in terms of a leap year instead of the current year.

**EDIT:**  Got it working for all cases, and as a useful query rather than a scalar select.  I'm using some extra subselects so that I don't have to type the same date or expression twice for month and day, and of course the actual data would be in a table instead of the `values` expression.  You might adapt this differently.  It might still stand to improve by making a more intelligent series for weeks containing leap days, since sometimes that interval will only contain 6 days (for non-leap years).

I'll try to explain this from the inside-out;  First thing I do is normalize the target date (`CURRENT_DATE` usually, but explicit in this code) into a year that I know is a leap year, so that February 29th appears among dates.  The next step is to generate a relation with all of the month-day pairs that are under consideration;  Since there's no easy way to do an interval check in terms of month-day, it's all happening using `generate_series`,

From there it's a simple matter of extracting the month and day from the target relation (the `people` alias) and filtering just the rows that are in the subselect.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (select column1 as birthdate, column2 as name
    from (values 
        (date '1982-08-05', 'Alice'),
        (date '1976-02-29', 'Bob'),
        (date '1980-06-10', 'Carol'),
        (date '1992-06-13', 'David')
    ) as birthdays) as people 
WHERE 
    ((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM people.birthdate), 
     EXTRACT(DAY FROM people.birthdate)) IN (
        SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM thedate.theday + s.a) AS m,
               EXTRACT(DAY FROM thedate.theday + s.a) AS d
        FROM 
                (SELECT date (v.column1 - 
                        (extract (YEAR FROM v.column1)-2000) * INTERVAL '1 year'
                       ) as theday
                 FROM (VALUES (date '2011-06-09')) as v) as thedate,
                 GENERATE_SERIES(0, 6) AS s(a)
        )
    )
```

Operating on days, as I've done here, should work splendidly all the way up until a two month interval (if you wanted to look out that far), since december 31 + two months and change should include the leap day.  On the other hand, it's almost certainly more useful to just work on whole months for such a query, in which case you don't really need anything more than `extract(month from ...`.

Comment: Well, this doesn't handle all cases. If today is Feb 28th of a non-leap year, the query doesn't return those born on Mar 6th of a non-leap year, when it should.

Comment: @sayap: I did mention that; but I'm not sure how to fix it, since there's no unique interpretation of "Feb 28 + 7 days" across any possible year.  I suppose you could increase the series to 8 days, or treat the current year differently if the current year is a leap year, but I'm not sure there's *one* right answer for that for all uses of this query, And so I didn't try to find a solution.

Comment: Well, for all cases I care about;  For all possible birthdays and all possible current years there exists at least one month/day such that the query will contain that birthday.  I don't claim that the ambiguity of leap year birthdays is solved by this query.

Answer (score 1):

First find out how old the person currently is using `age()`, then grab the year from that `extract(year from age())`. This is how old they are currently in years, so for their age at their next birthday add 1 to the year. Then their next birthday is found by adding an interval of this many years `* interval '1 year'` to their birthday. Done.

I've used a subselect here to add the `next_birth_day` column in to the complete table to make the select clause simpler. You can then play with the where conditions to suit your needs.

```
select * 
from (
     select *, 
       (extract(year from age(birth_date)) + 1) *  interval '1 year' + birth_date "next_birth_day"
      from public.users
) as users_with_upcoming_birth_days
where next_birth_day between now() and now() + '7 days'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Daniel Lyons's anniversary idea, by calculating the interval between the next birthday and today, with just +/- date arithmetic:

```
SELECT
    today,
    birthday,
    CASE
        WHEN this_year_anniversary >= today
        THEN this_year_anniversary
        ELSE this_year_anniversary + '1 year'::interval
    END - today < '1 week'::interval AS is_upcoming
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            today,
            birthday,
            birthday + years AS this_year_anniversary
       FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    today,
                    birthday,
                    ((
                        extract(year FROM today) - extract(year from birthday)
                    ) || ' years')::interval AS years
                FROM
                    (VALUES ('2011-02-28'::date)) AS t1 (today),
                    (VALUES
                        ('1975-02-28'::date),
                        ('1975-03-06'::date),
                        ('1976-02-28'::date),
                        ('1976-02-29'::date),
                        ('1976-03-06'::date)
                    ) AS t2 (birthday)
            ) AS t
    ) AS t;
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help!
I'm pretty new to PG, so little extra question @sayap, where to put the name of the table in your query? Little bit confusing for me :)

Comment: @Mike, you can replace the `(VALUES... AS t2 (...))` part with the table name, assuming it has a column named `birthday`.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want it to work with leap years:

```
create or replace function birthdate(date)
  returns date
as $$
  select (date_trunc('year', now()::date)
         + age($1, 'epoch'::date)
         - (extract(year from age($1, 'epoch'::date)) || ' years')::interval
         )::date;
$$ language sql stable strict;
```

Then:

```
where birthdate(birthdate) between current_date
                            and current_date + interval '1 week'
```

See also:

[Getting all entries who's Birthday is today in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758778/getting-all-entries-whos-birthday-is-today-in-postgresql/)

Comment: Careful with `BETWEEN <date> AND <date>`, as `BETWEEN` is inclusive at both ends. Also need to consider the case where current date is near the end of the year while birth date is near the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Exemple: birthdate between: jan 20 and feb 10

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE TO_CHAR(birthdate, '1800-MM-DD') BETWEEN '1800-01-20' AND '1800-02-10'
```

Why 1800?
No matter may be any year;

In my registration form, I can inform the date of birth (with years) or just the birthday (without year), in which case I saved as 1800 to make it easier to work with the date

Comment: What if you want birthdays between December 1st and January 31st in the following year?

Comment: Seems like good idea for using with Hibernate and Java, when you can set those "fake" dates from outside. Then you can make two queries for  (birthdate, '1800-MM-DD') and (birthdate, '1801-MM-DD') (for the case of January) and concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take, which works with leap years too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION days_until_birthday(
    p_date date
    ) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    v_now date;
    v_days integer;
    v_date_upcoming date;

    v_years integer;

BEGIN
    v_now = now()::date;
    IF (p_date IS NULL OR p_date > v_now) THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    v_years = date_part('year', v_now) - date_part('year', p_date);

    v_date_upcoming = p_date + v_years * interval '1 year';

    IF (v_date_upcoming < v_now) THEN
        v_date_upcoming = v_date_upcoming + interval '1 year';
    END IF;

    v_days = v_date_upcoming - v_now;
    RETURN v_days;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I had the same issue and came up with this simple and elegant solution:
It is pretty easy with age() and accounts for lap years... for the people who had their birthdays in the last 20 days:

```
SELECT * FROM c 
WHERE date_trunc('year', age(birthdate)) != date_trunc('year', age(birthdate + interval '20 days'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simply created this year date from original birth date.

```
( DATE_PART('month', birth_date) || '/' || DATE_PART('day', birth_date) || '/' || DATE_PART('year', now()))::date between :start_date and :end_date
```

I hope this help.

Comment: This breaks on leap days.