# Excel-VBA Calculate age from DOB when importing from SQL

Tags: sql, vba, postgresql, excel

I'm trying to import data from PGSQl into Excel and I ONLY want to import those that are aged <18y (dob) as of the eventdate.
Both the date of birth (dob) and eventdate imports as dd/mm/yyyy 00:00

How should I write this into my SQL code?

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select

Dim conn As New Connection
conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
conn.Open
Dim rs As Recordset

Dim ITEM As String
    ITEM = "SELECT user.id,surname,forename,dob,source.eventdate,source.item " _
    & "FROM source INNER JOIN user ON source.id=user.id " _
    & "WHERE ???? "

Set rs = conn.Execute(ITEM)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
```

Comment: Try this `WHERE (DATE_PART('year', eventdate) - DATE_PART('year', dob)) < 18`

Comment: [Possibly related.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913719/postgres-birthdays-selection)

Comment: I get a translation error; expected),got(

Comment: See PostGre's [age](http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/age.php) function: `WHERE extract(year from age(eventdate, dob)) < 18`

Comment: WHERE dob<=DATEADD("yyyy",-18,eventdate) ??