# Create function in database using django ORM

Tags: django, orm

In my project I want to get people who have birthday between some days, I hope to find a solution which does not force any limitations to queries.

I have found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17801120/2335245) which seems efficient and suite for my problem. But now I have a second problem to create the function in database using django ORM, because this must be portable and works with test database also. I could not find any proper way to able to define the function and the index based on it in django.

In brief I want to create below function in database using django:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION indexable_month_day(date) RETURNS TEXT as $BODY$
SELECT to_char($1, 'MM-DD');
$BODY$ language 'sql' IMMUTABLE STRICT;

CREATE INDEX person_birthday_idx ON people (indexable_month_day(dob));
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, using [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) you can insert raw SQL into a migration
 -- it looks like you should be able to put this raw SQL into a migration file, including the function that would create the custom index.  So running the migration would create the custom in

But **don't** do this -- you should just use Django to index the `dob` field, i.e.

```
dob = models.DateField(db_index=True)
```

and use Django to write your queries as well.

Comment: But `dob` is a `DateField` and I want just to use month and day from it and I try to do this as efficient as possible something like has explained in the post I have shared, so I think using just `db_index` is impossible for this manner.

Comment: If I use a raw sql statement in migration, how could I track this in my git repo? Do you think it is true to add this migration to git repo? I think this could corrupt migrations when another one get the repo and use `makemigrations` because the order migrations are applied could not define there.

Comment: Yes, it's standard practice to put migrations into your git repo.  Django migrations have some dependency order logic to ensure that they are run in the correct order.